# Is it possible to create, in XAML, a Style that is BasedOn one of the Device Styles in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I'd like to override one of the [Device Styles](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/device/) in a Xamarin.Forms app, but I only want to change one or two properties. Currently, I'm achieving this in code, like so:

```
Style listItemTextStyle = new Style(typeof (Label))
{
    BasedOn = Device.Styles.ListItemTextStyle
};
Setter wpListItemFontSizeSetter = new Setter
{
    Property = Label.FontSizeProperty
};
Device.OnPlatform(WinPhone: () => wpListItemFontSizeSetter.Value = 29.86);
listItemTextStyle.Setters.Add(wpListItemFontSizeSetter);
Application.Current.Resources.Add("FixedListItemTextStyle", listItemTextStyle);
```

But this has the disadvantage of being fairly noisy, and prevents other parts of the app from finding the style at design time.

So, is there a way I could achieve something like this?

```
  <Style x:Key="FixedListItemTextStyle" BasedOn="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize">
      <Setter.Value>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" WinPhone="29.86"/>            
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
```

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/device/

Comment: Yes. I linked it in my question. Is there further information on the page that you think I've overlooked, that would help answer my question?